# MTurk: show the survey link only after a HIT is accepted

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, mechanicalturk

I am using External Survey Link to create a project on MTurk. Is there any way to show the survey link only after a HIT is accepted?

I have been trying to check whether Crowd HTML Elements provided by Amazon can achieve this, but without any success so far...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the video here: It shows exactly what you want to do (I think).

https://research-it.wharton.upenn.edu/news/capture-mturk-workers-ids-qualtrics-survey/